# Using PHPUnit Groups

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

How can I configure groups of tests in PHPUnit? I find the docs a little lacking ... it just says

> The `<groups>` element and its
>   `<include>`, `<exclude>`, and `<group>`
>   children can be used to select groups
>   of tests from a suite of tests that
>   should (not) be run.
>
> ```
> <groups>
>   <include>
>     <group>name</group>
>   </include>
>   <exclude>
>     <group>name</group>
>   </exclude>
> </groups>
> ```

But how can I add directories/files into these groups?

Answer (score 10):

Add the [`@group` attribute](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group) to your test methods. A simple example from the linked docs:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @group specification
     */
    public function testSomething()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @group regresssion
     * @group bug2204
     */
    public function testSomethingElse()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can run PHPUnit mentioned in the documentation above:

```
{how you normally run phpunit} --group {GroupName}
```

Comment: Or you can exclude tests group on demand like this: `phpunit --exclude-group regression`.